# Writing testng tests with different java version than product's java version

Tags: java, testng

I need to analyze whether having different versions of java for product (AUT) and Tests (written using testng) will have any impact on test-ability of the AUT.
Lets say product is using Java 7 and the testNG tests are using Java 6 (JRE) to run [or vice versa]. Will this result in any kind of issues ?

The type of tests can be anything from unit, system, functional, integration, etc.

Please help.

Comment: Can you explain how your tests are running in a different JVM to the software it is testing?

Comment: Depending on your answer to @PeterLawrey's question, there is a high chance (at least for unit tests which are usually compiled and run together with production code) you won't be able to compile the project with java 6 the classes "developed" with 7 due to the differences between versions, such as `catch (IOException|SQLException ex)`

Comment: @PeterLawrey - I'm writing a wrapper fwk around testng, and currently it is in evaluation phase. For System tests, functional tests, where the product and tests would be running in different JVM, whereas in case of Unit Test, as said by Grove, it would be same JVM, where I won't be able to compile due to differences in version, for the reason that product might be using features of Java 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you have code written in Java 7 and a tests written in Java 6.  This is not a problem provided you have a JVM which can run Java 7 i.e. JRE 7+.

The fact some of the code is written in Java 1.1 or 5.0 or 6, or even compiled using this version doesn't matter.